# php objects: property Object Vs stdClass Object - which one is better?

Tags: php, properties, std

Sometimes I use `__get` or `stdClass` to convert **arrays to object**. But I can't decide I should stick to. I wonder which one is better and faster, any ideas?

```
class property 
{

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return (isset($this->$name)) ? $this->$name : null;
    }
}

$object = new property();
$object = new stdClass();
```

so if I use `new property()`, I will have a **property object** output,

```
property Object
(
....
)
```

while if I use `new stdClass()`, I will have a **stdClass object** output,

```
stdClass Object
(
....
)
```

so I can get the object data like this `$item->title`.

**EDIT:**

how I do the actual array to object conversion.

```
public function array_to_object($array = array(), $property_overloading = false)
    {

        # If $array is not an array, let's make it array with one value of former $array.
        if (!is_array($array)) return $array;

        # Use property overloading to handle inaccessible properties, if overloading is set to be true.
        # Else use std object.
        if($property_overloading === true) $object = new property();
            else $object = new stdClass();

        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $key = (string) $key ;
            $object->$key = is_array($value) ? self::array_to_object($value, $property_overloading) : $value;
        }

        return $object;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this technique.  You can use the property object you've created exactly as you would a stdClass object?

Comment: yes you can. but I am not sure if it is better than stdClass object or not...

Comment: You forgot to mention how you do the actual array to object conversion.

Comment: Do you have any benefits in using your own property class or just like I said as a data container?

Comment: sorry David, I don't understand - what do you mean by a 'data container'?

Comment: check this out - http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass

Comment: Take a look here, http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass

Basically, all you do is store data in your class (which is what I mean by data container). There are no methods or whatsoever applied to your property class which would make it preferable to a stdClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, an (almost) empty class definition like you have is almost like an `stdClass` so there won't be any major issues by using either.

That said, one advantage your "named" class has over `stdClass` is that you can define what happens when a non-existent property is being accessed by taking advantage of the `__get` magic method.

```
class property
{
   public function __get($name)
   {
       return null;
   }
}
```

The above is a simpler rewrite of your original `property` class; when `__get()` is being called, you already know that `$this->$name` is not set. Although this won't cause a notice, it doesn't prevent a fatal error when you try to reference `$obj->bla->bla` where `$obj->bla` doesn't exist.

It might be more useful to throw an exception when a non-existent property is being accessed:

```
class property
{
   public function __get($name)
   {
       throw new Exception("Property $name is not defined");
   }
}
```

This allows your code to catch the exception before it turns into a fatal runtime error that stops your script altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use your "property" class as a dumb data container, take stdClass or even an array.

Comment: **op** has asked which one is better ?